# Custom Properties Pane for a Winforms App

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, properties

I have seen apps before that have their own peoperties pane. How can I get me one of those? Searches on Google and MSDN haven't revealed any results, yet. I don't remember where I saw it, but it was based on an article and came as a sample app. Any help is appreciated! (Just like the one below)

Thank you

[image: Properties Pane]

Comment: *nods head* @Maxim Gueivandov, yup! Thanks to you :) You wanna put that as an answer? I'll accept and you'll get some shiny rep!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do you mean **[PropertyGrid](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.propertygrid.aspx)**?

Comment: That was quick :P - Thanks for your help :)